# What are the valid tags inside a update layout custom handler?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, layout-update

It seems the only child that is allowed in a custom handler is `<reference>` ?

I am trying to define a custom handler which has a `<block>` as a child, and it would only show the handle in the parsed handle list only when I used `<reference>` as first children in the custom handler tag content.

I am trying to define a custom handler to be used with `<update>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there was an answer here from another user which deleted it because I didn't reply, I presume.

His advice was to use `<reference name="root">` tag to solve this problem.

I've managed to improve his solution by using the method `setTemplate`.

So, I just wanted to show a particular child (content) via AJAX without any HTML wrapped on it.

I just did it with this bit of XML:

```
<catalog_category_updateview>
    <update handle="catalog_category_view"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/onlyContent.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_updateview>
```

And I've created the `onlyContent.phtml` template with a single call to `getChildHtml('content')`.

That did the trick.

If you are the guy which removed your answer, I thank you, and I apologize for the wait in my reply.